# Flat functors, flat modules, presheave category

Tags: derived-functors, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring considered as one obejct category. What is the precise relationship between flat functors in $[R^{op}, $ Ab] and flat modules?Here, by flat functors I understand those being directed colimits of representables.
If these are equivalent, how is it proved?